# Difference of property definition in component.xml (OSGI DS)

Tags: java, osgi

Could someone tell me the difference between this two property definitions?

```
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="blablaService">

   <property name="dbUrl" type="String">jdbc:h2:url</property>
   <property name="dbUser" type="String" value="user" />

</scr:component>
```

I'm using `Dictionary properties = context.getProperties();` to get the values. It seems to be that if the property given surround with xxx is treated as an Object holding a String[1] and the property which value is specified in the value attribute is treated as an Object which is de facto a String. For the first example (String) throws and Exception as the latter does not.

I'm developing using Eclipse and the Component Context is from `org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<property name="dbUser" type="String" value="user" />` yields a scalar String.

`<property name="dbUrl" type="String">jdbc:h2:url</property>` yields a String[1].

This is per the spec. See 112.4.6 in the Compendium Spec.

Comment: Thanks. I must have overlooked it at first.